# How to convert the URL path into image and showing on the list view

Tags: android

Based on the location i am trying to search the stores and search result is showing on the list view of the cell . I am getting the name,address,related Icons and rating from the Google but the problem is to how to show the Image on the list view of the list cell.I got the URL path of the Image.I also convert the URL path into bitmapImages using Bitmap getBitmapFromURL().But it is showing the NPE(Null POinter Exception). Below i am going to paste the code.

```
public class NearByActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
{
//    private ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView lvPlaces;
    ImageView ivPhone,ivCamera,ivPrinter,ivMore;
    String name,vicinity,formatted_phone_number,rating,icon;
    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;
    SharedPreferences spref;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
//    CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;

    public ImageLoader imageLoader;


    private static final String Name = "name";
    private static final String Vicinity = "vicinity";
    private static final String Rating="rating";
    private static final String Icon="icon";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nearby);

        lvPlaces=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPlaces);


        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);




        lvPlaces.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> MainActivity, final View view,int position, long id)
            {

                final TextView tvVicinity=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvVicinity);
                final TextView tvRating=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvRating);
                final TextView tvName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                final ImageView ivPhone = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPhone);
                final ImageView ivCamera = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
                final ImageView ivPrinter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPrinter);
                final ImageView ivMore = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivMore);

                ivPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Do you want the call",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Do you want to take pics",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                ivPrinter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Do you want to print",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                ivMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Do you want more",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                tvName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        String getName=tvName.getText().toString();
                        String getVicinity=tvVicinity.getText().toString();
                        String getRating=tvRating.getText().toString();

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(),Information.class);
                        i.putExtra(Name,getName);
                        i.putExtra(Vicinity,getVicinity);
                        i.putExtra(Rating,getRating);

                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }

        });

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null)

            {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,20000,0,this);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            sb.append("location="+mLatitude+","+mLongitude);
            sb.append("&radius=1000");
            sb.append("&types=beauty_salon");
            sb.append("&sensor=true");
            sb.append("&key=AIzaSyBgtVo5lfnDQFY8W44TfMevgg2klgj5WeA");

            // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
            PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
            placesTask.execute(sb.toString());
        }

    /** A method to download json data from url */

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
    {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb1  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null)
            {
                sb1.append(line);
            }
            data = sb1.toString();

            br.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
    }

    public  Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String icon ) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(icon);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }




    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        String data = null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url)
        {
            try
            {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>
    {
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData)
        {
            JSONObject jObject;
            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();
            try
            {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
                name = hmPlace.get("place_name");
                vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");
                rating=hmPlace.get("rating");
                formatted_phone_number = hmPlace.get("phone_number");
                icon = hmPlace.get("icon");
                placesListItems.add(hmPlace);

            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),""+icon,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            ImageView ivPics = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPics);
            ivPics.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(icon));



            ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(NearByActivity.this,placesListItems,
                    R.layout.myplace,
                   new String[]{"place_name","vicinity","rating","phone_number"},
                   new int[]{R.id.tvName,R.id.tvVicinity,R.id.tvRating,R.id.ivPhone});
            lvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

     }
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Activities.NearByActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(NearByActivity.java:328)
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Activities.NearByActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(NearByActivity.java:289)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: you can't use default adapter you have to make adapter custom

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
URL url = new URL("http://abcd.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
Bitmap bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add INTERNET permission to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**update 1:**

Also, are you sure that icon = hmPlace.get("icon"); is not null.

PS ivPics looks fishy to me.

**update 2:**

The problem I guess is the ivPics, I think it's null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Yes i already added the permissions.When i tried to debug the application I got the URL path but how to display the Image using the simple List Adapter

Comment: I am not sure sir.... sir if you have any other idea based on my complete program please tell me.

Comment: public  Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String icon ) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(icon); here when i add the breakpoint i got the Image URl.

Comment: @ Gautaw Yadav-Hi you are right sir the problem is in the ivpics only

Comment: in that case, could you mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @ Gauraw - hi i got the output actually in that case we need to make the Custom adapter.Inside the custom adapter we need to use the Imageloader for converting the Image and after that ivPics.display(icon,ivpics).